# Assign role by default in liquibase

Tags: java, postgresql, liquibase

How can i add particular user to changeSet and assign a role so when user access the service he/she can be ROLE_ADMIN by the default. I am using Liquibase and Postgres

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. Are you asking how to execute a `CREATE USER` statement in liquibase?

Comment: Exactly @Kayaman my appologies for unclear explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no [tags](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1346) for user management, but you can run anything you want in the generic `<sql>` tag, e.g.

```
<sql>
CREATE ROLE ROLE_ADMIN SUPERUSER;
</sql>
```

Comment: So it same for the Role i guess >            CREATE USER TEST@GMAIL.COM CREATE ROLE ROLE_ADMIN;

Comment: @ArtjomProzorov yes, well they're [synonyms](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-createuser.html). I'll edit it to be clearer.